# jQuery to get values of dynamically created multiple (>300) radio buttons

Tags: jquery, html

I am working on a science project. Basically it has an HTML table as shown in attached screenshot -
[image]

Sample jsFiddle is uploaded [here](https://jsfiddle.net/atultiwari/xpvt214o/247897/).

Sample HTML snippet is like -

```
<table>
<thead>
  <tr class="myHead">
   <th>Markers</th>
   <th>-</th>
    <th>1+</th>
    <th>2+</th>
    <th>3+</th>
    <th>+/-</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tr><td>CD1a</td><td><input type="radio" name="CD1a" value="0"></td><td><input type="radio" name="CD1a" value="2"></td><td><input type="radio" name="CD1a" value="3"></td><td><input type="radio" name="CD1a" value="4"></td><td><input type="radio" name="CD1a" value="1"></td></tr>
<tr><td>CD1b</td><td><input type="radio" name="CD1b" value="0"></td><td><input type="radio" name="CD1b" value="2"></td><td><input type="radio" name="CD1b" value="3"></td><td><input type="radio" name="CD1b" value="4"></td><td><input type="radio" name="CD1b" value="1"></td></tr>
<tr><td>CD1c</td><td><input type="radio" name="CD1c" value="0"></td><td><input type="radio" name="CD1c" value="2"></td><td><input type="radio" name="CD1c" value="3"></td><td><input type="radio" name="CD1c" value="4"></td><td><input type="radio" name="CD1c" value="1"></td></tr>
<tr><td>CD1d</td><td><input type="radio" name="CD1d" value="0"></td><td><input type="radio" name="CD1d" value="2"></td><td><input type="radio" name="CD1d" value="3"></td><td><input type="radio" name="CD1d" value="4"></td><td><input type="radio" name="CD1d" value="1"></td></tr>
<tr><td>CD1e</td><td><input type="radio" name="CD1e" value="0"></td><td><input type="radio" name="CD1e" value="2"></td><td><input type="radio" name="CD1e" value="3"></td><td><input type="radio" name="CD1e" value="4"></td><td><input type="radio" name="CD1e" value="1"></td></tr>
<tr><td>CD2</td><td><input type="radio" name="CD2" value="0"></td><td><input type="radio" name="CD2" value="2"></td><td><input type="radio" name="CD2" value="3"></td><td><input type="radio" name="CD2" value="4"></td><td><input type="radio" name="CD2" value="1"></td></tr>
<tr><td>CD3</td><td><input type="radio" name="CD3" value="0"></td><td><input type="radio" name="CD3" value="2"></td><td><input type="radio" name="CD3" value="3"></td><td><input type="radio" name="CD3" value="4"></td><td><input type="radio" name="CD3" value="1"></td></tr>
<tr><td>CD3d</td><td><input type="radio" name="CD3d" value="0"></td><td><input type="radio" name="CD3d" value="2"></td><td><input type="radio" name="CD3d" value="3"></td><td><input type="radio" name="CD3d" value="4"></td><td><input type="radio" name="CD3d" value="1"></td></tr>
<tr><td>CD3e</td><td><input type="radio" name="CD3e" value="0"></td><td><input type="radio" name="CD3e" value="2"></td><td><input type="radio" name="CD3e" value="3"></td><td><input type="radio" name="CD3e" value="4"></td><td><input type="radio" name="CD3e" value="1"></td></tr>
<tr><td>CD3g</td><td><input type="radio" name="CD3g" value="0"></td><td><input type="radio" name="CD3g" value="2"></td><td><input type="radio" name="CD3g" value="3"></td><td><input type="radio" name="CD3g" value="4"></td><td><input type="radio" name="CD3g" value="1"></td></tr>
<tr><td>CD4</td><td><input type="radio" name="CD4" value="0"></td><td><input type="radio" name="CD4" value="2"></td><td><input type="radio" name="CD4" value="3"></td><td><input type="radio" name="CD4" value="4"></td><td><input type="radio" name="CD4" value="1"></td></tr>
</table>
```

In reality, these Markers' list is generated from SQL database using Select Query (and are more than 300 in number). Name of the Radio buttons are kept same as column name of the Marker in database table along with their respective values.

Now, what I am trying to achieve (and failing to do so) is, **whenever a radio button is clicked, it should create a list/array of all the selected radio buttons with their respective values in such a manner that, it can be used to create another `Select` query.** For e.g. if selected radio buttons are like (values of selected radio buttons are in bracket)- CD1b(2), CD2(4), CD4(1); so the final query would be like -
`Select * from my_table where CD1b=2 and CD2=4 and CD4=1;`

Sample jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("input:radio").click(function() {
   //Logic to find out all the selected radio buttons in way that can be used to create an SELECT MySQLi Query
  })

})
```

I know how to find out selected radio button, but I don't know how to do the same in dynamically created multiple radio buttons groups.

Comment: Instead of adding 1500+ event handlers add one on the table. Wrap the table in a form and use [`.serializeArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)

Comment: You need [delegated event handlers](http://api.jquery.com/on/) - `$('table').on('click', 'input:radio', handler)`

Comment: @Andreas Thank you so much, got the logic

Comment: @Andreas No need to wrap them in a form. `.serializeArray()` works fine on collections of inputs too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.serializeArray()`, like this (see [forked JSfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/7k13gbne/)):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $inputs = $("input:radio");
  $inputs.change(function() {
    var state = $inputs.serializeArray().reduce((acc, datum) => {
      acc[datum.name] = datum.value;
      return acc;
    }, {});
    console.log(state);
  });
});
```

The `state` will then look like

```
{"CD1c":"2","CD1e":"3","CD3e":"4"}
```

which you can POST to your backend or do whatever with.

Comment: Thank you so much. I got the logic, I didn't know if something like this exist. I will accept the answer as soon as SO allows me to (4 mins wait)

Comment: @Dr.AtulTiwari But you should really use delegated events here.

Comment: I agree with that :) `$(document).on('change', 'input:radio', function() {...`) would work better.

Comment: @Andreas I am going through the link posted by wiesion about delegated events and will see how can I make use of it (as I am still learning)